# Python (*NIX): Is it possible to list aliases from calling shell?

Tags: python, bash, aliases

I am trying - within a python script - to list all of the aliases that were defined in the shell that launched this python script.

Essentially I am looking for an analogous method to **os.environ** but one that would let me list the aliases in shell that called this python script (whether it returns a dict or list or string is not important).

Note: I am *not* trying to execute these aliases. I merely want to
list them.

I have tried `subprocess.call("alias", shell=True)` but it merely `returns "0"`. I'm fairly sure that the subprocess is not the way to do it anyway. As far as I know, subprocess fires up a whole new shell which, even if it were to somehow read my .bashrc file, would not necessarily have the same aliases as the shell that called my python script.

In this particular case, the calling shell is a bash shell but I'd like to be able to extend this ability to other shells as well.

Is something like this even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no way to access a list of aliases in the calling shell. Aliases are "shell-local" information that isn't exposed in any form to child processes.

Comment: That's what I feared. Thanks! If you want to post this as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: How about "grep alias .bashrc .profile"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had considered that but it is not an accurate representation of the actual aliases in the shell, only those that may have been set by bash on startup. Since that time more may have been added or removed or altered. My solution at the moment is to wrap my script in a shell script and pass the existing aliases as an argument to the python script.